# No files in res/layout when creating a new Android Project(Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: android, xml, ubuntu, layout

I'm following the tutorials that google has on their website for creating and running an application. 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p this is the tutorial link

anyways so I can create the project but I run into 2 problems that are stopping me from making any progress: when I try to run the app from an emulator or my physical device, the app installs but it doesn't show up in the app drawer. however it does show up as installed in my application manager under settings.
The second problem is there are no files located in the res/layout folder, which means I can't move on past the second part of the tutorials or do anything at all

If anyone has run into the same problems or has a solution I'd greatly appreciate it as I'm antsy to start learning

Comment: which IDE are you using? Eclipse I presume? Try finding a new>activity option. I'd strongly recommend Android Studio though.

Comment: Yea I'm using eclipse because the tutorials provide are for eclipse. I guess I might try to adapt them to android studio....